# How can i insert dynamic textbox values into database table on same ID using php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, database

I need to insert dynamic text box values into database table on same id,now I can possible for inserting values on different user id only.

when i am trying to insert dynamic text boxes values into database table on id 1,the dynamic text boxes values going to different id like 2,3,4 and so on.And also becoming zero field values of id 1.https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPWTt.png

here's my html and javascript code:

file name:index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
    <SCRIPT src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></SCRIPT>
        <style>
        table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th, td {
        padding: 5px;
        }
        table{
        background-image:  #eee;
        }

        </style>

    </head>

<body>

    <form name="registration" id="regis" method="post" enctype="multipart/formdata">
        <table>

                <th colspan="1">
                <th>Details Mahall members</th>
                </th>

            <tr>
                <td>Name of the person:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name1" id="fname1" placeholder="Enter name" value=""/>
                </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>Name of the father:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name2" id="fname2" placeholder="Enter name" value=""/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Name of the mother:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name3" id="fname3" placeholder="Enter name" value=""/>
                </td>
            </tr>



            <tr>
                <td>Details of family members:</td><td></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <th><center>No:</center></th><th><center>Name</center></th><th><center>Age</center></th><th><center>Relation<strong></th><th><center>Occupation<strong></th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>

                <td>
                <DIV id="product">
                        <DIV class="product-item float-clear" style="clear:both;">

                            <?php require_once("sub.php") ?>

                        </DIV>
                    </DIV></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td> <DIV class="btn-action float-clear">
                    <input type="button" name="add_item" value="Add More" onClick="addMore();" />
                    <input type="button" name="del_item" value="Delete" onClick="deleteRow();" />
                    <span class="success"><?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; }?></span>
                </DIV>
                </td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>

                <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit"/>
                <input type="reset" value="cancel"/>

            </td><td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>


    </form>
    <SCRIPT>
function addMore() {
    $("<DIV>").load("sub.php", function() {
            $("#product").append($(this).html());
    }); 
}
function deleteRow() {
    $('DIV.product-item').each(function(index, item){
        jQuery(':checkbox', this).each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(item).remove();
            }
        });
    });
}
</SCRIPT>
</body>
</html>
```

file name:sub.php

```
<DIV class="product-item float-clear" style="clear:both;">
<DIV class="float-left"><input type="checkbox" name="item_index[]" /></DIV>
<table cellspacing="2"> 
 <tr>

<td><DIV class="float-left"><input type="text" name="name1[]" style="width:60px"/></DIV></td>
<td><DIV class="float-left"><input type="text" name="name2[]" style="width:90px"/></DIV></td>
<td><DIV class="float-left"><input type="text" name="name3[]" style="width:62px"/></DIV></td>
<td><DIV class="float-left"><input type="text" name="name4[]" style="width:130px"/></DIV></td>
<td><DIV class="float-left"><input type="text" name="name5[]" style="width:178px"/></DIV></td>
</DIV>
</tr>
</table>
```

here's my php code for inserting into database

```
<?php
$username="root";
$password="sha12345";
$hostname="localhost";

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die("Could not connect to database");

$select = mysql_select_db("sha", $dbhandle);


    if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
    $personname = $_POST['first_name1'];
    $fathername = $_POST['first_name2'];
    $mothernname = $_POST['first_name3'];


    mysql_query("INSERT INTO sha(Name_person,Name_father,Name_mother)   VALUES ('$personname','$fathername','$mothernname')");  



        if(!empty($_POST["save"])) {


        $itemCount = count($_POST["name1"]);
        $itemValues=0;
        $query = "INSERT INTO sha (no_members,name_members,age_members,relation_members,occupation_members) VALUES ";
        $queryValue = "";
        for($i=0;$i<$itemCount;$i++) {
            if(!empty($_POST["name1"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["name2"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["name3"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["name4"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["name5"][$i])) {
                $itemValues++;
                if($queryValue!="") {
                    $queryValue .= ",";
                }
                $queryValue .= "('" . $_POST["name1"][$i] . "', '" . $_POST["name2"][$i] . "', '" . $_POST["name3"][$i] . "', '" . $_POST["name4"][$i] . "', '" . $_POST["name5"][$i] . "')";
            }
        }
        $sql = $query.$queryValue;
        if($itemValues!=0) {
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if(!empty($result)) $message = "Added Successfully.";
        }
    }
    }
    mysql_close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ok, so here are the steps you can follow**

**Create Table users**

```
CREATE TABLE users(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   Name_person VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   Name_father VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   Name_mother VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);
```

**Create Table family_members**

```
CREATE TABLE family_members(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   user_id INT NOT NULL,
   no_members TINYINT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
   name_members VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   age_members VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   relation_members VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   occupation_members VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);
```

**Then in your PHP Code**

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(Name_person,Name_father,Name_mother) VALUES ('$personname','$fathername','$mothernname')");  


$user_id = mysql_insert_id();

$query = "INSERT INTO family_members (user_id,no_members,name_members,age_members,relation_members,occupation_members) VALUES ";
$queryValue = "";
for($i=0;$i<$itemCount;$i++) {
    if(!empty($_POST["name1"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["name2"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["name3"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["name4"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["name5"][$i])) {
        $itemValues++;
        if($queryValue!="") {
            $queryValue .= ",";
        }
        $queryValue .= "('".$user_id. "', '" . $_POST["name1"][$i] . "', '" . $_POST["name2"][$i] . "', '" . $_POST["name3"][$i] . "', '" . $_POST["name4"][$i] . "', '" . $_POST["name5"][$i] . "')";
    }
}
$sql = $query.$queryValue;
```

**And further you can easily get records with JOIN or just simply**

> Let say you want get record of user 1

```
$get_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1");
$user = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_user);
$user_id = $user['user_id'];


echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><th colspan="5">Recod of User '.$user['Name_person'].'</th></tr>';
$get_user_family = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM family_members WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");
while ($family = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_user_family))
{
    echo"<tr><td>".$family['no_members']."</td><td>".$family['name_members']."</td><td>".$family['age_members']."</td><td>".$family['relation_members']."</td><td>".$family['occupation_members']."</td></tr>";
}
echo '<table>';
```

Comment: Thank you,actually i can insert all values of dynamic text box already  into table,but i can't able to insert on same id.

Comment: Thanks bheem raj,I can insert second query correctly,but the problem is on values goes to different id's.you can checkout my attached snapshot now,than you will get understand  easily what i am trying to ask.

Comment: Oh, You should have two tables for this, let say `1. users`, `2. fmembers`, and should have `one-to-many` relation between them, LIKE: create new field `user_id` in `fmembers`. Then store `Name_person,Name_father,Name_mother` in `users` table, get  `user_id = mysql_insert_id()`. Store other info like `no_members etc` in `fmembers` table with this `user_id`.

Comment: -Really thanks for helped me,now i can insert second query into family_members table,i got an error like undefined user_id,but now i cleared that error.also listed users and family_members details from both tables.really appreciated bheem raj.

Answer (score 1):

You can take array of inputs in HTML like `name="first_name[]"`

```
<input type="text" name="first_name[]" id="fname1" placeholder="Enter name" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="first_name[]" id="fname2" placeholder="Enter name" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="first_name[]" id="fname3" placeholder="Enter name" value=""/>
```

Then while fetching in php, You can just write

```
print_r($_POST['first_name']);
```

That will contain all values in array

Comment: Really thanks for helped me bheem raj,i followed like u edited,but values not getting insert now,should i create text box in html for inserting into database table.